# Close dropdown after pressing enter in autocomplete textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a textbox with autocomplete mode. When I enter any value, dropdown appears with the suggestion items, I use down arrow key to scroll down and when I hit enter key, the selected item is taken by the textbox but the dropdown is not closing.

If I select any value in suggestion items using mouse click, selected item is taken by the textbox and dropdown is closing automatically. How do I achieve this behaviour after I hit enter?

I don't find any property related to this issue.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection ac = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
ac.AddRange(this.Source());

if (textBox1 != null)
{
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ac;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

It is because on textBox1_TextChanged event. I had a code

```
this.AcceptButton=button1;
```

To resolve, I removed the above line.

For active button, I used the following code

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```